# Is there way to copy data from the GCP data catalog from a project to another?

Tags: google-data-catalog, google-dataplex

I'm doing a test to use GCP Data Catalog (DataPlex) to document tables from Big Query.
I'm doing in a dev project, in the future, I'd like transfer data that I documented (description of columns, overview of table) from dev project to prod project?
Is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate what `BG` means? It would also help if you give an example of the “descriptions, columns” that you want to transfer.

Comment: Hi @AnjelaB, thanks for the comment, I updated the question."descriptions columns" are content that I filled in each column of table in catalog (dataplex)

Comment: Is this for viewing purposes only? Alternatively you can filter the project id of your dev project in data catalog while using prod project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/mesmacosta/datacatalog-util is an export/import utility that lets you achieve what I believe you are looking for, provided that you use tags to store these descriptions?